# Content Security Policy on Leaflet slide menu plugin

Tags: javascript, plugins, leaflet

I have transfered my application on another server that have a strong CSP and I can't modify that roule. I have implemented a leaflet map and I have used a leaflet slide menu plugin.
Well, that plugin have some problem with CSP and I don't have found a solution. In particular the plugin have a problem on that line of code

```
setContents: function(innerHTML){ this._innerHTML = innerHTML; this._contents.innerHTML = this._innerHTML; },
```

Can someone help me to fix please?

Comment: Why did you decide that the problem is related to CSP? If CSP violations occur, a corresponding message about blocking should appear in the console, add it to the question. And show the strict CSP of this new server.

Comment: @granty in fact the console gives me this message 
Content Security Policy: Le impostazioni della pagina hanno rilevato il caricamento di una risorsa su inline (“script-src”). È stata inviata una segnalazione CSP. 8 L.Control.SlideMenu.js:90:8

Comment: Looks like by means of `function(innerHTML) {...}` in line of code you shown, an inline script is injected. To solve the issue a code refactoring or `'unsafe-inline'` token in the `script-src` directive required.